# How to create common source for different services with NestJS?

Tags: nestjs

For example, this is book.service.ts

```js
    import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
    import { Book } from '../interfaces/book.interface'

    @Injectable()
    export class BooksService {
        private readonly books: Book[] = [];

        private create(book: Book) {
            console.log(book)
            this.books.push(book);
        }

        private findAll(): Book[] {
            return this.books;
        }
    }
```

Another buy.service.ts

```js
    import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
    import { Book } from '../interfaces/book.interface'

    @Injectable()
    export class BuyService {
        private readonly books: Book[] = [];

        private findAll(): Book[] {
            return this.books;
        }
    }
```

The `private findAll()` methods are the same in the two files. How to create a common logic for them?

Comment: Why would your `BuyService` implement a `findAll` for `Book[]`?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Actually it's necessary for another service need to find all books. Just for this case, I want to know if it's possible to make common method for different services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I'd inject the `BookService` into the `BuyService` and not make the `findAll()` method `private`. This way you can call `this.bookService.findAll()` from within the `BuyService`. Otherwise, you'll need to abstract up another layer and inject that abstraction into both `BookService` and `BuyService`.

Sounds like overall tightly coupling code, so be cautious you don't end up with crossed domain lines and tightly coupled dependencies

Comment: Thank you. It looks a good idea. Inject one to another service is possible. So it needs to keep the main logic at one service place. I also thought about make common logic at `lib/common/findBook.ts`, but it looks not a good way.